# How to achieve login authentication in Excel add-in using OfficeJS

Tags: authentication, authorization, office-js

We are using Excel add-in in OfficeJS and wanted to implement login authentication with below requirements.

1. we have own on-premise server (identity),
2. need to achieve access and refresh token.

Kindly suggest any examples for the same.

Answer (score 0):

An add-in is just a web application embedded in Office. so you would implement login auth exactly the way you would for any web application. If you are using OAuth 2.0, then for resources and libraries about how to do this, see [Authorize external services in your add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins). The one possible exception is that some identity providers (Secure Token Services) do not allow their login page to open in an iframe. If that is the case with the STS that you will be using, then you will need to open the service's login page in a special dialog. For more information, see [Authorize with the Office Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api).